# ng-Toast with Angular using $scope'd object/elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtoast

I haven't been able to find this information using the sparse ng-Toast documentation.

I have a list of objects that I set a $scope.notifications to. I would like these objects to appear in the 'toast'. I set '$scope.notifications = x;' and then my ng-Toast looks like this:

```
                ngToast.create({
                  content: $scope.notifications,
                  compileContent: true,
                  compileToScope: $scope
                });
```

However, I only see '[object] [object] in the toast that appears.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 'yes you can'.

Example:

```
            $scope.notifications = x;
            ngToast.create({
                content: '{{notice.content}}',
                compileContent: true,
                compileToScope: $scope
            });
```

Neat.